# Select all record by foregin key which is on ArrayList distinct ORMLite

Tags: java, sql, ormlite

Im want to create a querybuilding which gives me distinct list of tables by the list of objects on the ArrayList which are foregin keys.

```
ArrayList<ForeginKeys> list;
List<AimObjects> main_list = All tables which foregin keys on the list is equal on the main_list distinct
```

UPDATE:

I have Two models Object1 and Object2

Object1 is a foregin key for Object2

I have a list of Object1 and want to get list of Objects2 which have Object1(which are in the list) as a Foregin Keys, Distinct.

Comment: these detail is not sufficient, plz brief.

Comment: You want the names of the tables or the entities in the tables?  Can you edit your post a bit more to be more clear what you are asking?